# WPF binding with explicit conversion

Tags: wpf, data-binding, type-conversion, converters

My question may be a repeat of other conversion question but I feel mine is different.

Here goes... [simplified example].

```
public class DataWrapper<T>
{
    public T DataValue{ get; set; }

    public DataWrapper(T value)
    {
        DataValue = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator DataWrapper<T> (T value)
    {
        return new DataWrapper<T>(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(DataWrapper<T> data)
    {
        return data.DataValue;
    }
}
```

Now, in my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DataWrapper<string> FirstName { get;set; }
    public DataWrapper<string> LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
```

My question is, will this work? Will WPF binding call the `Implicit` and `Explicit` converter in my `DataWrapper<T>` class instead of needing to implement a `IValueConverter` for each `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't say whether it would work or not, as I haven't tested it. However, if it doesn't work, you can try using a `TypeConverter` for your `DataWrapper` type.

For example:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DataWrapperConverter))]
public class DataWrapper
{
    ...
}

public class DataWrapperConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return (DataWrapper<string>)value;
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

You can use the generic helper methods on the Type class to deal with your type conversion more dynamically.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Could you also link me the the generic helper methods you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

No, WPF will not call the implicit converter.  You must use a value converter or Paul's TypeConverter suggestion.

Comment: 3 lines of code for the implicit conversion. Another 17 to tell WPF to use it. Plus the extra instance allocated with every single binding. That’s typical WPF, isn’t it.